# Template argument deduction failed for function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

The compiler is failing to deduct template argument for function pointer.

```
template< class Function >
class foobar {
    Function f;
public:
    foobar(Function _f) : f(_f) {}

};
```

The function definition is

```
bool foo(string a, string b) {
    // SOMETHING
}
```

I'm getting trouble in the following line

```
foobar f(foo);
```

The compiler error

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘f’
```

Comment: Template argument deduction applies to function templates, not to class templates.

Comment: @KerrekSB, there was a proposal for templated constructor, though - if memory serves?

Comment: @SergeyA: [P0091](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r1.html) perhaps. But that doesn't help or apply to the OP...

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes, but it would help OP with a small modification of their code.

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB. But it can be determined by the compiler during the compile time right? Then why such a feature is not implemented anyway. Is there anyway other way, I can do the same

Comment: @OutOfRange: It's not implemented because the language rules forbid this. The compiler has to follow the language rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to deduce type of the object by templated constructor. However, maker functions can help:

```
template<class T>
foobar<T> make_foobar(const T& t) {
    return Foobar<T>(t);
}

...
auto f = make_foobar(foo);
```